# MariaDB - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed Error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB and the DB schema looks like this:

[image]

And I've created those tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, I didn't defined the foreign key when I created the table. But I am trying to use `alter` manipulation command to make a reference between two tables like this:

```
ALTER TABLE member ADD FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES follow(uid);
ALTER TABLE member ADD FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES follow (following_uid);
ALTER TABLE member ADD FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES feed (uid);
```

The first one was successful. But the other ones, I get this error:

```
Can't create table `SimpleSNS`.`#sql-6b94_5f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I checked `InnoDB` and the columns data type and its prototypes such as default or not null, etc. However, It didn't work.

What's the problem of this???

Comment: Did the `ALTERs` in the wrong order.

Comment: Well, I tried one by one. But didn't work.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLEs` so we can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on "follow (following_uid)" before executing -> ALTER TABLE member ADD FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES follow (following_uid);

Comment: why should I need to create an index?

Comment: Other db's these kind of foreign key creation works,but in current version of Mariadb  its not working, may be bug? so to work you should use either of below two workarounds. 1. Create index, or 2. Disable fk checks before creating fk and later enable it. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and then SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;